# installing OpenSwan xl2tpd for IPSEC/L2TP VPN

Tags: software-installation, vpn, openswan

I have a VPS hosted with QuickWeb.co.nz  Running Ubuntu 12.04 OpenVZ.

I downloaded and unpacked OpenSwan, but I still cannot install:

```
root@vps:~/openswan-2.6.35# apt-get install openswan xl2tpd ppp 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Package ppp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package openswan
E: Unable to locate package xl2tpd
E: Package 'ppp' has no installation candidate
```

I admit to being a novice, I am learning as I go. Thanks for your patience and help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

try to do `apt-get update` first to update the package list of apt first then try again